# Use Regex to form a number without leading zeros in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, qunit

I'm having trouble forming a regular expression that can strips out leading zeros from numbers represented as strings. Sorry but parseFloat isn't what I'm looking for since I'll be dealing with numbers with 30+ decimal places.

My current regular expression is

```
/(?!-)?(0+)/;
```

Here are my test cases.
http://jsfiddle.net/j9mxd/1/

```
$(function() {
    var r = function(val){
        var re = /(?!-)?(0+)/;
        return val.toString().replace( re, '');
    };
    test("positive", function() {
        equal( r("000.01"), "0.01" );
        equal( r("00.1"), "0.1" );
        equal( r("010.01"), "10.01" );
        equal( r("0010"), "10" );
        equal( r("0010.0"), "10.0" );
        equal( r("10010.0"), "10010.0" );
    });
    test("negative", function() {
        equal( r("-000.01"), "-0.01" );
        equal( r("-00.1"), "-0.1" );
        equal( r("-010.01"), "-10.01" );
        equal( r("-0010"), "-10" );
        equal( r("-0010.0"), "-10.0" );
        equal( r("-10010.0"), "-10010.0" );        
    });
});
```

Why are my test cases not passing?

Comment: Please provide some insight in what is actually going wrong, and asking an actual question may not hurt either.

Comment: The question is "why aren't my tests passing?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This finishes all your cases

```
var re = /^(-)?0+(?=\d)/;
return val.toString().replace( re, '$1');
```

`^` matches on the start of the string.

`(-)?` matches an optional `-` this will be reinserted in the replacement string.

`(0+)(?=\d)` matches a series of 0 with a digit following. The `(?=\d)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it does not match but ensure that a digit is following the leading zeros.

Comment: @LarryBattle I added an explanation

Answer (score 2):

This passes your tests, and is relatively easy to read:

```
var r = function(val){
    var re = /^(-?)(0+)(0\.|[1-9])/;
    return val.toString().replace( re, '$1$3');
};
```

Comment: Very cleaver using of the back-references.

Comment: a lookahead is a better solution - I would have edited the answer but stema proposed it first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
var r = function(val) {
    var re = /(-)?0*(\d.*)/;
    var matches = val.toString().match(re);
    return (matches[1] || '') + matches[2];
};
```